# Statsmodels ARIMA - Different results using predict() and forecast()

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I use `ARIMA` from [statsmodels](/questions/tagged/statsmodels) package in order to predict values from a series:

```py
plt.plot(ind, final_results.predict(start=0 ,end=26))
plt.plot(ind, forecast.values)
plt.show()
```

I thought that I would get the same results from these two methods, but instead, I got this:

[image: img]

I would like to know whether to use `predict()` or `forecast()`.

Comment: as `statsmodel` documentation suggests, `predict` is used for in-sample predictions and `forecast` is just for out-of-sample predictions. [predict](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict), [forecast](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast)

Answer (score 25):

From the chart it looks as if you are doing out-of sample preictions with `forecast()`, bit in-sample predictions with predict. Based on the nature of the ARIMA equations, out-of-sample forecasts tend to converge to the sample mean for long forecasting periods.

In order to find out how `forecast()` and `predict()` work for different scenarios, I compared various models in the `ARIMA_results` class systematically. Feel free to reproduce the comparison with `statsmodels_arima_comparison.py` [in this repository](https://github.com/noteven2degrees/timeseries). I looked into each combinations of `order=(p,d,q)`, only restricting `p, d, q` to 0 or 1. For instance, a simple autoregressive model can be obtained with `order=(1,0,0)`.
In a nutshell, I looked into three options, using the following [(stationary) time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3l0U.png):

A. Iterative in-sample forecasting form a history. The history was formed of the first 80 % of a time series, and a test set was formed by the last 20 %. Then I forecasted the first point of the test set, added the true value to the history, forecasted the second point etc. This shall give an evaluation of the model predictive quality.

```
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=order)
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=-1)
    yhat_f = model_fit.forecast()[0][0]
    yhat_p = model_fit.predict(start=len(history), end=len(history))[0]
    predictions_f.append(yhat_f)
    predictions_p.append(yhat_p)
    history.append(test[t])
```

B. Next, I looked into out-of-sample forecasting by iteratively predicting the next point of the test series, and appending this prediction to the history.

```
for t in range(len(test)):
    model_f = ARIMA(history_f, order=order)
    model_p = ARIMA(history_p, order=order)
    model_fit_f = model_f.fit(disp=-1)
    model_fit_p = model_p.fit(disp=-1)
    yhat_f = model_fit_f.forecast()[0][0]
    yhat_p = model_fit_p.predict(start=len(history_p), end=len(history_p))[0]
    predictions_f.append(yhat_f)
    predictions_p.append(yhat_p)
    history_f.append(yhat_f)
    history_f.append(yhat_p)
```

C. I used the `forecast(step=n)` parameter and the `predict(start, end)` parameters in order to do internal multi-step forecasting with these methods.

```
model = ARIMA(history, order=order)
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=-1)
    predictions_f_ms = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(test))[0]
    predictions_p_ms = model_fit.predict(start=len(history), end=len(history)+len(test)-1)
```

It turned out that:

A. Forecast and predict yield identical results for AR, but different results for ARMA: [test time series chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKuBM.png)

B. Forecast and predict yield different results for both AR and ARMA: [test time series chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWRKk.png)

C. Forecast and predict yield identical results for AR, but different results for ARMA: [test time series chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG86h.png)

Further, comparing the seemingly identical approaches in B. and C. I found subtle but visible differences in the results.

I suggest that the differences result mainly from the fact that "prediction is done in the levels of the original endogenous variable" in `forecast()` and `predict()` produces prediction of differences in levels ([compare the API reference](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast)).

Further, given I trust more the internal functionality of the statsmodels functions than my simple iterative forecasting loop (this is subjective), I would recommend going with `forecast(step)` or `predict(start, end)`.

Answer (score 7):

Continuing noteven2degrees's reply, I submitted a pull request to correct in method B from `history_f.append(yhat_p)` to `history_p.append(yhat_p)`.

Also, as noteven2degrees suggested, unlike `forecast()`, the `predict()` requires an argument `typ='levels'` to output a forecast, instead of a differenced forecast.

After the above two changes, method B produces the same result as method C, while method C takes far less time, which is reasonable. And both converges to a trend, as I think is related to the stationarity of the model itself.

No matter in which method, `forecast()` and `predict()` produce the same result with whatever configurations of p,d,q .