# Fitting Regression Model to Time-Series Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, regression

I am trying to fit a regression model to a time series data in Python (basically to predict the trend). I have applied seasonal decomposition using `statsmodels` earlier which extracts data to its three components including the data trend.
However, I would like to know how I can come up with the best fit to my data using statistical-based regressions (by defining any functions) and check the sum of squares to compare various models and select the best one which fits my data. I should mention that I am not looking for learning-based regressions which rely on training/testing data.
I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this or even introduces a tutorial for this issue.

Comment: What's wrong with scikit learn? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: @K. Shores Thanks for your comment. I checked the link...but it seems this is only for linear regression? I would like to examine various regression models...like polynomial, exponential, sinusoidal and even their combinations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure scikit learn has options for all of those. Search their documentation

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned:

> I would like to know how I can come up with the best fit to my data using **statistical-based regressions** (by defining any functions) and check the sum of squares to compare various models and select the best one which fits my data. I should mention that I am **not** looking for learning-based regressions which rely on training/testing data.

Maybe [`ARIMA`](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/) (Auto Regressive Integrated **Moving Average**) model with given setup (P,D,Q), which can learn on history and [predict()](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.predict.html)/[forecast()](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#generated-statsmodels-tsa-arima-model-arimaresults-forecast--page-root). Please notice that split data into train and test are for sake of evaluation with approach of walk-forward validation.

**Tested in `python 3.11.4`, `pandas 2.1.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.2`, `sklearn v1.2.2`, `statsmodels v0.14.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

# load dataset
def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('199'+x, '%Y-%m')

# read into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('shampoo_sales.csv', header=0)

# format the Month column as datetime64[ns]
df.Month = df.Month.apply(parser)

# split into train and test sets
X = df.Sales.values
size = int(len(X) * 0.66)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()

# walk-forward validation
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(5,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    # print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
    
# evaluate forecasts
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predictions))
rmse_ = 'Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse

# plot forecasts against actual outcomes
plt.plot(test, label='test')
plt.plot(predictions, color='red', label='predict')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Sale')
plt.title(f'ARIMA model performance with {rmse_}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please see other [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45596492/10452700) & [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31690134/10452700) for further info. Maybe you can add [trend line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808699/10452700) too

#### `shampoo_sales.csv`

```
Month,Sales
1-01,266.0
1-02,145.9
1-03,183.1
1-04,119.3
1-05,180.3
1-06,168.5
1-07,231.8
1-08,224.5
1-09,192.8
1-10,122.9
1-11,336.5
1-12,185.9
2-01,194.3
2-02,149.5
2-03,210.1
2-04,273.3
2-05,191.4
2-06,287.0
2-07,226.0
2-08,303.6
2-09,289.9
2-10,421.6
2-11,264.5
2-12,342.3
3-01,339.7
3-02,440.4
3-03,315.9
3-04,439.3
3-05,401.3
3-06,437.4
3-07,575.5
3-08,407.6
3-09,682.0
3-10,475.3
3-11,581.3
3-12,646.9
```